# Of Gold and Silver

Tags: riddle

Gold makes me.
Silver is my enemy.

Who am I?

---

Hint:

> This riddle is based on a saying

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Speech is silver, but silence is golden.

So we have

> Silence

Comment: That was quick, but correct! Just so i know, did you need to use the hint? BTW, can you edit and put your answer in a spoiler, for other people? Thanks!

Comment: @Nathan Shiraini Where I'm from the german version of this saying is relatively well known, so it was the first thing i thought about when reading the riddle.